# 3d Modelling: Creating driver license theory book images

Tags: images, image-processing, 3d, simulation, modeling

I'd like to create images suitable for a (European) driver license theory book (see below). My criteria are all "nice to haves", I'd be interested to hear software recommendations that do not meet all criteria:

- Runs using a low/mid range graphic card.
- Doesn't cost more than 400 euros.
- Should preferably run on Linux, but Windows would do as well.

If there is a tool which can easily create one of the images below, but not the others, I would be interested to hear about it as well.

[image] 
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clear case for [**Blender**](https://www.blender.org/) in my opinion. Freeware, super-robust, Linux, Mac and Windows, and exceptionally powerful and flexible - enough so that despite being freeware, it's finding acceptance in the 3D industry in commercial pipelines - because it does what it does quite well.

Hope that helps.